Topological defects in terms of homotopy classes of maps between spheres
I have some troubles with understanding the concept of topological defects and their treatise via homotopy groups of spheres as discussed in wikipedia article. More precisely,
if we encode these in terms of different (pointed) homotopy classes of
$[S^n,S^m]_*= \pi_n(S^m,*)$ what from physical point of view plays the
role of domain sphre $S^n$ and what of codomain sphere $S^m$?
In wikipedia article the "Overview" paragraph seemingly contradict to "Formal treatment" paragraph
on what is actually the domain and what is codomain in this modelling:
The "overview" paragraph tells:

The general characteristic needed for a topological soliton to arise is
that there should be some partial differential equation (PDE) - eg
the Korteweg-De Vries (KdV) equation - having distinct
classes of solutions, with each solution class belonging to a distinct
homotopy class. In many cases, this arises because the base space -- 3D space,
or 4D spacetime, can be thought of as having the topology of a sphere,
obtained by one-point compactification: adding a point at infinity.
This is reasonable, as one is generally interested in solutions that vanish
at infinity, and so are single-valued at that point. The range (codomain)
of the variables in the differential equation can also be viewed as living
in some compact topological space. As a result, the mapping from space(time)
to the variables in the PDE is describable as a mapping from a sphere to a
(different) sphere; the classes of such mappings are given by the homotopy
groups of spheres.

How I understood this part so far: We start with a PDE - lets take
eg the Korteweg-De Vries equation - describing the system's dynamics
$$  \partial_t \phi + \partial^3_x \phi - 6\, \phi\, \partial_x \phi =0\, \quad x \in \mathbb{R}, \; t \geq 0 $$
and want to inspect homotopy theoretically the structure of space of its
solutions $\phi(x,t)$ where $t \in \Bbb R_{\le 0}$ is the time and $x \in 
\Bbb R$ resp $\Bbb R^3$ the spatial coordinate.
So let pick such a solution $\phi: \Bbb R_{\le 0} \times \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R $.
We assume that it vanishes at infinity as the text assumed, ie $\phi(t, x) \to 0$
for $\vert x \vert, t \to \infty$, so here comes this compactification part into
game: We extend the domain $\Bbb R_{\le 0} \times \Bbb R^3$ of $\phi$ by
adding "at infinity" the point "$\infty$" such that
$\Bbb R_{\le 0} \times \Bbb R^3 \cup \{\infty\} \cong S^4$ and extend
$\phi$ to $\infty$ via setting $\phi(\infty):=0$; that seems to be what they meant
by "reasonable" assumption that $\phi$ vanish at infinity. Firstly, is that they procisely meant there by that the solution should vanish at infinite?
If yes, so we get $\phi: S^4 \to \Bbb R$.
First intermediate problem: Isn't this already null homolotopical? (Then to analyze it with homotopical methods would be meaningless)
Next they write, that "The range (codomain) of the variables in the
differential equation can also be viewed as living in some compact
topological space." What do they mean precisely by "range of the variables in the
differential equation"? Just the image $\phi(S^4)$? But I doubt that
this is what they mean, as $\phi$ constructed that way would be again
homotopically to zero map as $\Bbb R$ is contractible.
Question: It seems that either I misunderstand what is written there
or the quoted paragraph describes it wrongly as the way how I understood it would lead to conclusion that any such solution $\phi$ considered as map would be null homotopic, but that's not what we want. If the former is the case and I'm missing
some issue, could somebody elaborate how correctly to understand the
described construction turning certain solutions of the given PDE into homotopy classes of certain maps of spheres?
Even more obscure, what is the connection of this construction to the
homotopy groups of type $\pi_i(R)= \pi_i(G/H)=[S^i,G/H]$ where $R$ is the pararameter space
and $G$ acts on it with stabilizer $H$ described in "Formal treatment"
paragraph? What has the parameter space $R$ to do with the solutions $\phi$ of the equation above?
The strange thing is that in "overview" paragraph once dealt with
homotopy classes of maps $\phi:S^n \to S^m$ coming from solutions/configurations
of the PDE dscribing the dynamic of the system, so $S^n$ (resp $S^m$) was just the domain (resp. codomain) of a solution function $\phi$. In "Formal treatment"
paragraph on the other hand, the codomain is no longer the codomain of the solutions $\phi(x,t)$, but the parameter space
$R=G/H$. So its "point" are cerain solutions of the PDE itself.
How to relate the descriptions from "Overview" and "Formal treatment"? Does one consider homotopy classes of solutions of the PDE, or the abstract
parameter space?
NB: My problem is not the pure mathematics behind homotopy theory but only the physical part to "merge" things together discussed in wikipedia's "Overview" and "Formal treatment" paragraphs.

I wish I could answer all your questions but am just a bloody beginner in the field of topological solitons myself. The books by N. Manton, and P. Sutcliffe are fairly rigorous. Probably best to start with Skyrmions - A Theory of Nuclei by the first author. In short: the Skyrmion field is $SU(2)$-valued and Manton denotes it by $U,.$ Its domain is, as you say, the one-point compactified $\mathbb R^3,.$ This makes it a continuous map from $S^3$ to $S^3$ and as such it has a winding number (the Baryon number). Start reading that book not just WP articles. It is fun.

@KurtG.: Maybe a naive question of a non physicist: If we pick two such Skyrmion fields (=solutions of certain PDE) $\phi, \psi: S^3 \to SU(2)$. What does it physically mean if they are mathematically homotopic (resp non homotopic) to each other? Which physical implication do we draw from this?

A naive guess: In quantum physics in order to do perturbation theory one needs a unique vacuum field (...and then essentially the excitations around it behave like quantum harmonic oscillator around it). What is the role of such solutions $\phi$ from viewpoint of QFT? A guess: Would (non) homotopic $\phi, \psi$ "play" the role of vacuum giving by effective /perturbative approach (non) equivalent theories?

I am not even a physicist myself :). Tony Skyrme was one. As far as I understand all this: the physics comes in when a Lagrangian is introduced so that one can speak of energy. Topologically two non homotopic field configurations cannot be transformed into each other without ripping one of them apart. The energy that is required to do that (and prevents a configuration to become unstable) is what Skyrme has added to that model of atomic nuclei. Afaik, Skyrme's fields are not operator valued (not a QFT).

I am not overly mathematical myself.  I will just give aworking example with the simplest possible topological object: vortex in two spatial dimension.
First of all, there should be a field (solution of PDE) that takes value in $S^{1}$.  Think the direction of magnetization in the 2D plane, or the phase of a superfluid order parameter.
And then let us draw a loop in the 2D space, and look at the magnetization direction/order parameter phase as a function of position along the loop.  This is your mapping from $S^{1}$ (spatial loop) to $S^{1}$ (solution).  You can now talk about the homotopy class, which is just the winding number.
If the winding number is non-zero, you know that inside the loop there must be some singularity; it is thus called a "defect" because you have to remove at least one point in the plane to hide the singularity.  Physically this is usually accomplished by the medium not being in the magnetic/superfluid phase in a small region.  Or you can literally punch a hole.
Now, why does the field configuration take value in $S^{1}$ in the first place?  More often than not it is the result of a spontaneous symmetry breaking.  For instance, any quantum theory should be invariant under a global U(1) phase rotation.  The ground state is often just invariant as well.  But the superfluid order parameter spontaneously breaks this symmetry.  U(1) rotation is a symmetry of the entire theory in the sense that, if you U(1)-rotate any superfluid state, you get another distinct but degenerate state.  Individually, not even (any one of) the ground state is invariant.
In this simple case, $G = U(1)$ and there is no remaining "unbroken" symmetry, so $H$ is trivial.  Then we know that the degenerate solutions can be labelled by $G/H = U(1) = S^{1}$ (abusing the equal sign).
(In fact, if that $S^{1}$ is not somehow symmetry-protected, we can't talk about a definite value in $S^{1}$ in the first place.  So I guess symmetry breaking is the mechanism.)
You can now generalize to e.g. magnetization in 3D wrapping around a 2-sphere.  A magnetization vector is invariant under axial rotation, so $H = O(2)$, and we assume the base theory is $O(3)$-invariant, fully isotropic in 3D.  So the order parameter space is $O(3)/O(2) = S^{2}$.  Non-trivial wrapping give a skyrmion.  And inside that spatial 2-sphere again you know there must be a defect.
--edit--
Honestly the wiki article is very badly written and I can't decipher half the mumble-jumble.  You should read some actual textbooks to get a better idea.
Concrete example of superfluid vortex in 2D:
The simplest form of superfluid can be described by a complex scalar order parameter field $\psi$:
$$\psi: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$$
The problem of finding static solution of the full theory corresponds to the minimization of the free energy functional
$$
F[\psi] = \int \! d^2 x \;
(\nabla\psi^{*})\cdot(\nabla\psi) + \frac{\lambda}{2} (\vert \psi\vert^2 - \mu)^2
$$
$\delta F/\delta\psi = 0$ is a PDE.
The free energy itself is U(1)-invariant under $\psi \rightarrow e^{i\theta} \psi$, but obviously any $\psi \neq 0$ solution is not.  At each point where $\psi$ is non-vanishing, it's local value can be characterized by $U(1) = S^1$.
There will be no distinct homotopy class whatsoever if $\psi \neq 0$ everywhere.  Set $\psi = 0$ at one point $\vec{r}$, and only now you get non-trivial homotopy when considering
$$
\psi/\vert\psi\vert : \mathbb{R}^2/\lbrace\vec{r}\rbrace \rightarrow S^1.
$$
And finally you can shrink $\mathbb{R}^2/\lbrace\vec{r}\rbrace$ to just an $S^1$ loop as far as homotopy is concerned.
Alternatively, punch a hole $\mathbb{R}^2$ from the very beginning.  Bottomline is, you always need a defect for there to be non-trivial honotopy.

Just to clarify if I understood the gist/idea correctly, so let's stick on this "toy example" with vortex in two spatial dimension from 2nd to 4th paragraphs: So the base setting is that we consider fields $\phi: \Bbb R^2 \to S^1$ (ie from 2D space to circle $S^1$ which are by definition solutions of certain PDE.  ... let call the space of all these $\Phi$ (Physically this may considered eg as continuous associations of a magnetization direction vector to any point in 2D space $\Bbb R^2$.)

Then in 3rd paragraph we restrict such a picked $\phi$ to diverse loops $L:=S^1 \subset \Bbb R^2$, so consider $\phi \vert _L \to S^1$, resp their homotopy classes $[\phi \vert _L] \in \pi_1(S^1)$. Now fix such a loop $L:=S^1 \subset \Bbb R^2$ and vary solutions $\phi$ of the PDE. Then this would induce a map $f_L: \Phi \to \pi_1(S^1) = \Bbb Z, \phi \mapsto [\phi \vert _L]$. And then one can partition the $\phi$'s depending on which integer their image
under $f_L$ in $\pi_1(S^1)$ take. Is this the correct idea attepting to phrase it in "mathematical" terms?

Is this precisely the procedure refered to in wiki link "that there should be some partial differential equation (PDE) having distinct classes of solutions, with each solution class belonging to a distinct homotopy class."? And such distinction of the $\phi$'s is carried out in the way attepted to describe in my previous comment via this func $f_L$? (esp, explicit choices - that of $L$ - are always tactily involved?)

I think you have the right idea.  I won't attempt to interpret the wiki mumble-jumble further.

Could you maybe clarify what is the physical interpretation of such static solution from QFTheoretical picture? I thought that when one want to do perturbative theory (essentially mimic quantum HO around some fixed - so especially unique - "vacuum solution) the crucial question to choose what plays actually the role of vacuum; so the choice would allow to do perturbation but the price to pay is that we loose info about other choices. Now my guess is are nonhomotopical classes precisely the "candidates" for vacua, which once fixed and subjected to do perturbation theory around one such

would give in general non equivalent effective perturb theories? In turn, if $\phi, \psi$ are homotopic static solutions, is the gist of this that perturbation theories around these - considering these as vacuum solution - would be "equivalent" (in appropr sense)?

@user267839 You can certainly say that the static solution is a background around which you do perturbation theory.  But bear in mind that it is a field configuration just like any other within the path integral language.  In modern time people tend to regard such defect as just another type of excitation that exists in the Hilbert space of the quantum theory, that has dynamical evolution and all that.  (At least as far as I know, people who call themselves field theorists (as opposed to people who use QFT) gravitate toward that direction.)

I mean, people no longer care about the precise semiclassical solution, but just the fact that such excitation exists.  Much of its properties can be inferred from topology alone.

How then would you characterize what should be meant by "static solutions" and how to contrastthem  from those that are well, non static? Ie, what is the "gist" for calling a configuration "static" in field theory?

Actually "static" probably a misleading term.  It is only static semi-classically.  You just take the classical field equation and require the classical solution be time-independent, and that is it.  You can treat the solution as a classical background of your QFT, this is what you do to study e.g. electron bound states in a vortex.  Or you take the existence of such solutions as guidance, and consider fully quantum excitations that has the same topology.  The latter approach is the foundation of many field theoretic dualities at the heart of modern studies of topological this-and-that.
